# Create Custom Report - for what these Site Search Goals appears in metrics?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

[image: screenshot]

What does it mean - Goal 10 (Site Search Goal 1...) - about 20 items, Goal 2... - about 20 items, etc.?
Ok, I understand what is Site Search mean.
I couldn`t understand, for what these Goals are if I didn`t create any Goals in my GA account and on my sites with site search?
How could I use these metrics if in my account there are not these goals?
Why they appear?

Answer (score 1):

When you don't know the meaning of a metric, just simply hover your cursor on the question mark on the side.

Anyway, Site Search Goal X is when a user uses the internal search on your website and then converts for the Goal n° X (goals have a specific and numbered position at the time you create them).

So, if for example your Goal 2 is a thank you page, Site Search Goal 2 tells you the number of visitors who uses the internal search and at some point they reach the thank you page.

If you didn't set any Goal, these metrics are useless.